# Percent change with grouping variables

Tags: sql, hql, hiveql

I have four grouping variables `Month`, `State`,`County`, `City`. In addition I have the metric column `sales` which can be null I would like to calculate the percent change of sales per month for each `City`. 
My solution would have the same grouping but with the `sales` column replaced by percent change for each month in calendar year 2019.  Any help with a solution is appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select month, state, city, sales,
       lag(sales) over (partition by state, city order by month) as prev_month,
       (-1 + sales / lag(sales) over (partition by state, city order by month)) as change_ratio
from t;
```